# JavaFx: How can I get the combobox object from it's textfield?

Tags: javafx, combobox, textfield

I have a combobox (cb). When someone clicks on the associated textfield, I want to clear it. I use

```
cb.getEditor().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent evt) {
        ((TextField) evt.getSource()).clear();
    }
});
```

and the result is in cb.getEditor().getText() 
So far so good.
If I fill the box via the pull down instead of typing the result is in `cb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();`
That's good too. The combobox is populated with an object, not a string, so I can't really use getSelectedItem(). I wish I could.
The problem is, if I try to select something from the pulldown, and THEN use the editor, the selectedIndex() remains set.
How can I clear the combobox selectedIndex when I have a mouse event for the textfield? I can't find a way to get the combobox from the textfield.
I don't know if it's relevant but I also tie the text to the box via `TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(cb.getEditor(), cb.getItems()));`

Comment: "The combobox is populated with an object, not a string, so I can't really use `getSelectedItem()`. " Why not?

Comment: Strangely, NetBeans won't let me. If I try, `cb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSomeObjectProperty()` it compiles but at runtime I get a "Not a property of Java.Lang.String"

Comment: How do you run it if NetBeans doesn't let you do it? Did you set a converter on the combo box?

Comment: That's the odd thing. I'm compiling/running in NB but while I can compile, when I run it and look at the selectedItem() it says it's a string. I cannot do (MyObject) (...getSelectedItem()) ; it says I can't convert the string to the object.

Comment: Did you set a converter? The documentation explicitly states that if the combo box is editable and its type is not `String`, you must set a converter. *"By default the converter simply returns the String input as the user typed it, which therefore assumes that the type of the editable ComboBox is String. If a different type is specified and the ComboBox is to be editable, it is necessary to specify a custom StringConverter."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ComboBox` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html):

> Because a `ComboBox` can be editable, and the default means of allowing
>   user input is via a `TextField`, a string `converter` property is provided
>   to allow for developers to specify how to translate a users string
>   into an object of type T, such that the value property may contain it.
>   By default the `converter` simply returns the `String` input as the user
>   typed it, which therefore assumes that the type of the editable
>   `ComboBox` is `String`. If a different type is specified and the `ComboBox`
>   is to be editable, it is ***necessary*** to specify a custom
>   `StringConverter`.

(my emphasis).

Therefore, you need to provide a converter for your `ComboBox` that defines how to convert the string the user typed in the combo box editor into an object of the correct type, and conversely how to convert an object of that type into a string to display in the text field.

Once you have done that, the correct way to retrieve the value from the combo box is with

```
cb.getValue();
```

Comment: I am only an egg.  I did not know about StringConverter. I did some research and set it up for my cb but I still have a problem ~ if someone types gibberish into the textbox, it still returns the most recent selection. That was my original problem!

Comment: @Megabuttons Your converter needs to handle "gibberish" in some sensible way.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. What I didn't see is a way to identify the nonsense without looping through my source list again. I'm game to try though!